# Что делать с неиспользуемым методом в наследуемом классе?

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть базовый абстрактный класс с некоторыми методами.

Эти методы используют большинство производных классов.

Но для одного типа класса функция не нужна.

Например:

```
const MyStruct& childClass::getMyStruct()
{
    return что?
}
```

У `childClass` не может быть члена `MyStruct`, чтобы его вернуть.

Всё-таки как сделать правильно? Сунуть объект, чтобы был, или есть нормальное решение?

Comment: класс абстрактный. компилятор просит переопределить все методы

Comment: Если в производном классе что-то не требуется, скорее всего что-то не так с архитектурой наследования.

Comment: да, одно из решений просто убрать этот метод из абстрактного класса. очевидно.

Comment: А это виртуальный метод?

Comment: да, это виртуальный метод

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Измените иерархию. Абстрактный класс БЕЗ этого метода, его наследник - абстрактный класс С ним. И соответствующие наследники - от основного абстрактного класса - тот ваш производный, для которого реализация невозможна; все остальные - производные от производного абстрактного.

Comment: это хороший ответ, но разве абстрактый класс не имеет право просто этот метод иметь как не чистый виртуальный, но иметь другой чистый виртуальный метод?  Тогда все вопросы отпадают....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Перепроизнесите :) В смысле, могут ли в одном классе быть как чисто виртуальные, так и "конкретные" методы (с телом, а не =0)? Да, конечно. Более того (хотя не буду спорить, если мне возразят), насколько я помню, даже чисто виртуальная функция может иметь тело - т.е. типа `func(...)=0{...}`, и это тело вполне вызываемо (по крайней мере VC++ позволяет).

Answer (score 4):

Если в базовом классе определены абстрактные методы, то возможны два варианта

1. Эти методы описывают некий интерфейс работы с этим классом. Тогда эти методы должны иметь уровень видимости public и будут вызываться снаружи класса. Тогда наследник понятия не имеет какие методы будут вызываться
2. Эти методы вызываются из других методов этого класса. Тогда наследник просто обязан их переопределить для обеспечения работоспособности базового класса

В любом случае наследник не имеет никакого права говорить, что какие-то методы не нужны. Если наследник не может реализовать тот или иной метод, то сам наследник должен быть абстрактным.

Если абстрактный метод не принадлежит ни одной из этих двух категорий, то он никому не нужен и должен быть удален из класса.

---

Исключение может составлять случай, когда наследник управляет алгоритмом работы родителя. Что-то типа такого

```
class Base {
  virtual bool compare() = 0;
  virtual const MyStruct& getMyStruct() = 0;
  virtual const MyStruct& getMyOtherStruct() = 0;
  void doSomething() {
    MyStruct = struct1;
    if (compare())
      getMyStruct() = struct1;
    else
      getMyOtherStruct() = struct1;
  }
}
```

тогда если мы определим в дочернем классе

```
class Child:public Base {
  bool compare() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

то мы можем быть уверены, что метод `getMyOtherStruct` не вызовется никогда. Тогда мы можем просто ничего из него не возвращать, а просто бросить исключение

```
const MyStruct& getMyOtherStruct() {
  throw "Call abstract method";
}
```

Но нужно помнить об одной особенности. Никто не мешает сделать так

```
class Child2:public Child {
  bool compare() {
    return false;
  }
}
```

тогда компилятор уже не сможет предупредить, что не все методы определены и если забыть самому переопределить getMyOtherStruct то получите законный exception

Answer (score 3):

Если, несмотря на возможные архитектурные изъяны с наследованием, функция всё таки нужна, можно предложить заменить ссылку хотя бы на указатель. И возвращать в таком случае `nullptr`. Хотя, как я считаю, наличие функции в базовом классе должно подразумевать ее существование во ВСЕХ производных классах. Иначе, стоит задуматься о создании более расширенной иерархии классов.

Answer (score -1):

```
const MyStruct& childClass::getMyStruct();
```

Попробуй.

```
throw;
return *(MyStruct*)(nullptr);
```

Но толку в ретурне этом 0.

Comment: Нельзя сделать переопределяемую функцию удаленной.

Comment: virtual попробуй добавить

Comment: [Доброе утро](https://www.onlinegdb.com/r1wCs1C4f) .

Comment: virtual void test_func();
метод как бы есть но вызвать его нельзя. вообще илпользовать указатели в с++ нестоит ибо есть shared_ptr;